# Массивы в php

Tags: массивы, php

Добрый день.

Есть код, который заносит значения в массив, но при такой организации, массив перезаписывается и в него заносятся только последние данные.
Вопрос: как нужно изменить код для работоспособности скрипта?

```
$input = $dom->find('input[id="reg_username"]');
$fieldname = array('login' => $input[0]->name);

$input = $dom->find('input[id="reg_email"]');
$fieldname = array('email' => $input[0]->name);

var_dump($fieldname);
```

Вывод:

> array(1) { ['email']=> string(32)
> "some@email.ru" }

Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
$fieldname = array();

$input = $dom->find('input[id="reg_username"]');
$fieldname['login'] = $input[0]->name;

$input = $dom->find('input[id="reg_email"]');
$fieldname['email'] = $input[0]->name;
```

Comment: Так конечно работает, но разве нельзя в таком случае использовать функцию array() ?

Comment: array() - создает новый массив. А вам надо дополнять старый.<br>
Изложите в понятном виде свою задачу если хотите получить разумный ответ